# Using curl with the -o- option

Tags: curl

I see a lot of examples online like this:

```
curl -o-  <url> | bash
```

isn't the -o- option just writing to stdout? why not just omit it? or maybe that -o- option is doing something else? is there a way to make it more explicit?

```
curl --stdout  <url> | bash
```

Comment: `-o-` is superfluous, just remove it. `curl <url> | bash` works perfectly

Comment: probably just a force of habit for people using wget (where it does make a difference)